# How to test a symfony2 embedded controller with phpunit?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, controller, phpunit, functional-testing

I am using embedded controllers to generate dynamic content in side templates(eg: a menu)

Usually, I implement functionnal tests to assert controllers.
So far, functionnal tests are passing and phpunit considers my embedded controllers code-covered

I am wondering how to test the embedded controller with different inputs and evaluate the outputs... Is that Unit Testing right ?

I know Unit Testing controller is a bad practice, but how can I function test an embedded controller when there is no Request Object ? 
The route/url is something that the Twig render() function takes care of.

`{{ render(controller('AppSuperBundle:Default:generateMenu', {'params': ... } )) }}`

An example to illustrate:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        return $this->render('AppSuperBundle::index.html.twig');
    }

    public function generateMenuAction($route, Array $RouteParams)
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(...
        //some process to generate params of menu items (eg:locale, url, name...)

        return $this->render('AppSuperBundle::menu.html.twig', array('menuItems' => $menuItemsWithParams));
    }
}
```

The template `index.html.twig`

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% block menu %} 
        {{ render(controller('AppSuperBundle:Default:generateMenu', {'route': app.request.attributes.get('_route'), 'RouteParams': app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')} )) }}  
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}
        ...
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

What are your thoughts on this ?

Comment: I think, generally you should not try to embed the output of controllers in this way. Have you checked out https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I use doctrine, translatable, sluggable and tree to generate my i18n hyperlinks. As far as I know, KnpMenuBundle only uses translation files. My code is clear and is working with only one controller function and a template so I don't see the need to implement a service and customize it. Which is the way embedded controllers should be implemented ?

Comment: In my training with Ryan Weaver, Symfony core member and main documentation writer, he generally discouraged me from using Controllers in non standard ways as a matter of convention.. But I was trying to do things like call a Controller from within another Controller. Bad juju. Back to your original question, I think you can test the route where your embedded Controller resides. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#your-first-functional-test. You can pass different parameters, and use the crawler to find expected output based on your request

Answer (score 0):

Your embedded controllers do not exist in a vaccum. They are being loaded by templates used in your main controllers.

I would say that it is sufficient to only check main controllers. If you really want to check different output from embedded controllers just test the main controller with appropriate params. In the end it is the main controller that is pasing different values to your embedded controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Since render a view is the response, and you are talking about unit test,
And i would highly recommend unit test the controllers, since in some projects the controllers can have a lot of logic there.
i would unit test a controller to its behavour,so it won't throw strange error from the code in the controller. so what i suggest you to do is create a test method for each case in each action, and you will probably need to mock some of the objects the controller is using, here is an example:

```
public function testIndexAction()
{
    $this->employeeRepository->expects($this->once())->method('findByFilter')->will($this->returnValue($this->employee));
    $this->entityManager->expects($this->once())->method('getRepository')->will(
        $this->returnValue($this->employeeRepository)
    );


    $this->employeeManager->expects($this->once())->method('formatEmployeeData')->will(
        $this->returnValue($this->formattedJson)
    );


    $this->mockContainer($this->object);

    $this->object->indexAction();

}
```